# oracle apex trigger mouse click over region using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, mouseclick-event

I have 3 regions in my apex page. R1,R2 and R3. R1 is a tabular region. R2 and R3 are sub regions of R1. I  want to trigger a fake mouse click event on region R3 when a button is clicked, using javascript. so to trigger mouse click on region R3 ( static id: R3 ) I used the code

```
 $('#R3').trigger("click");
```

But that doesn't work. When I inspected the page, I found the region id as 'SR_R3_tab'. So I changed the code to

```
$('#SR_R3_tab').trigger("click");
```

That didn't made any progress . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what APEX version you are using. But I tried to reproduce your flow [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=80759:4).

What I basically did:

- Parent child has a button 'Trigger Click'
- Added dynamic action on click on that button, where the action is execute javascript: `$('#R35171256286597705402').trigger("click");`
- List item `R35171256286597705402` is the id of the child region. Not sure why yours is not following this format, because usually APEX generates these ids. But I fetched from inspecting
- To validate, I added another dynamic action, but this time on click on the child region. It basically displays the alert

[image]